# nginx configuration for proxy from subfolder to subdomain

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to proxy from main domain to subdomain like that;

**example.com/blog** => *blog.example.com*

**example.com/blog/test** =>  *blog.example.com/test*

I use this configuration :

```
 location /blog/ {
        proxy_pass  http://blog.example.com;
    }
```

But when I go to url **example.com/blog** , it redirects me to **blog.example.com/blog** or

**example.com/blog/test** ,it redirects me to **blog.example.com/blog/test**.

How can I remove /blog from subdomain which comes from main domain proxy?

Comment: It is okey for /blog/ but for example.com/blog/test => blog.example.com/test how can i achieve this

Comment: This does not work. example.com/blog , it redirects me to blog.example.com/blog